# Font is not being loaded

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm at my wits end with this problem. I'm trying to include a font. The **CSS file** is located at `project/css/`.
My **font** is located at `project/fonts/iconfont/`.
I have the following font files in that folder (even though I'd probably only need woff):

```
icons.eot
icons.svg
icons.ttf
icons.woff
```

This is how I try to include my font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: icons;
    src: url(../fonts/iconfont/icons.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

However I can't use the font. Checking with Chrome developer tools it doesn't even load. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If fonts aren't loading then console must having `Get` or `404` error.

Comment: is your server set up to serve woff files?  I think you usually have to add the mime-type if you use iis

Comment: have you tried to add all of the file formats to see if anything loads?

Comment: have you tried to add all of the file formats to see if anything loads?       
font-family: 'icons';
src: url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.eot');
src: local("☺"),
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('f../fonts/iconfont/icons.svg#icons') format('svg');

Answer (score 0):

Try to link all fonts format in @font-face selector and call font-family with custom name in quotation marks.

```
/*--- Define a custom web font ---*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'YourWebFont';
  src:
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.ttf') format('ttf'), 
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.eof')  format('eof'),
     url('../fonts/iconfont/icons.svg')  format('svg');
}
/*--- Use that font on the page ---*/
body {
  font-family: 'YourWebFont', sans-serif;
}
```

Good luck!